# form to json error when there is a dynamic list operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, form2js.js

There is a addresses in my APP, there is a button that will add address if neccessary, but when I transfer the form to object and use ajax submit, the form object will only contain the last address. here is the  [`demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/5cKd2/3/)

**EDIT**

this issue has been partial fixed, but we still think about if remove function is added, how we control the index of the list, if anyone has a good idea, you can give me a comment, thanks, and thank for the help from @weeksdev

Comment: You're overwriting the same property of the same object over and over again.

Comment: @ErikReppen but I want to privide a list to the background, just like {addresses:[{name:1},{name:2}]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the input objects `name` is the same for all inputs. Modifying the name to iterate and all inputs show in output.  Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLm8M/1/) out for example

Here is the correspoding code with the change:

**Option 1:**

```
$(".addAddress").click(function(){
    $("#addressEare").append(' <br><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="person.addresses.name' + i + '" value="address'+i+'" class="addressName" />');
    i++;
});
```

**Option 2:**

If you are looking to get an array of objects with a `name` property then the corresponding code would be this:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="i_form">
    <div id="addressEare" name="">
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="person.addresses[0].name" value="address1" class="addressName" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Address" class="addAddress"/>
    <input type="button" value="Show Form Object" class="showFormObj"/>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var i=2;
$(".addAddress").click(function(){
    $("#addressEare").append(' <br><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="person.addresses[' + i + '].name" value="address'+i+'" class="addressName" />');
    i++;
});
$(".showFormObj").click(function(){
    var formObj = form2js("i_form",".");
    alert(JSON.stringify(formObj));
});
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLm8M/3/) demonstrating option 2

Comment: It is cool for option2, I fixed the issue and [here is the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jLm8M/4/)